# How We can check isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) in app.module and SSR rendering

Tags: angular, window, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using ssr rendering, and I have a problem using window and its values in my app.
Now I can get property of window using the following code:

```
@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
         console.log(window.appConfig.apiBaseUrl)
      // this.apiBaseUrl = window.appConfig.apiBaseUrl;
    }
}
```

My question is following how I can access **window.appConfig.apiBaseUrl** in the bellow code, which in
turn config of RestangularConfigFactory:

```
export function RestangularConfigFactory(RestangularProvider) {
  // TODO - change default config

  RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl(window.appConfig.apiProxy);
  RestangularProvider.addFullRequestInterceptor((element, operation, path, url, headers, params) => {
    // Auto add token to header
    headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    headers.platform = window.appConfig.platform;
    return {
      headers: headers
    };
  });

  RestangularProvider.addErrorInterceptor((response, subject, responseHandler) => {
    // force logout and relogin
    if (response.status === 401) {
      localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
      localStorage.removeItem('isLoggedin');
      window.location.href = '/auth/login';

      return false; // error handled
    }

    return true; // error not handled
  });
}
```

Comment: Where is `window.appConfig` set?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a service and inject the platformId in the service. It worked for me.